# Cleveref-like command in ConTeXt

Tags: cross-referencing, context, cleveref

Following [ConTeXt garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Proclaim), I set up theorem environments like in the below MWE. I wonder if ConTeXt has a command similar to `\cref` from the LaTeX package `cleveref` which automatically adds "Corollary,", "Theorem," "Remark," etc. in front of all references. Preferably, this should work the way that if I should later decide to change a corollary into a remark, the references should automatically be updated accordingly.

*Side question:* How do I stop ConTeXt from inserting those line breaks after the theorem numbers?

```
% mode=mkiv

\defineenumeration[remark]
[text=Remark,
location=serried,
width=fit,
right={.~}]
\setupenumerations[remark]
[prefix=yes,
% or prefixsegments=chapter:section
prefixsegments=section] 
\setupnumber[remark][way=bysection]

\defineenumeration[theorem]
[text=Theorem,
location=serried,
width=fit,
counter=remark, % only use counter of remark
style=italic,
right={.~}]
\setupenumerations[theorem]
[prefix=yes,
prefixsegments=section]

\defineenumeration[corollary]
[text=Corollary,
location=serried,
width=fit,
counter=remark, % only use counter of remark
style=italic,
right={.~}]
\setupenumerations[corollary]
[prefix=yes,
prefixsegments=section]

\starttext


\startremark
This is a silly remark.
\stopremark

\starttheorem
This is a deep theorem.
\stoptheorem

\startcorollary[easyresult]
This is an easy corollary.
\stopcorollary

I want \cref[easyresult] to work like \in{Corollary}[easyresult].

\stoptext
```

Obviously, it does not compile at the moment (`\cref` is not a command), but what I want is

[image]

Comment: If you insert a  `\def\cref[#1]{\in{Corollary}[#1]}` before your `\starttext`, it will produce that output you see.

Comment: Ye,s but it will write Corollary before *all* result references, including theorems. That is not what I want.

Comment: My bad. I forgot about that. BTW, if you want to prevent those linebreaks, you must use `alternative=` instead of `location=`. See http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupenumerations

Comment: Also, I found [\setupreferencestructureprefix](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupreferencestructureprefix). It seems it might be able to do the trick; however, it is badly documented, and so far, I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define `\cref` as follows:

```
\definereferenceformat[cref][label=*]
```

Then, for all enumerations, define:

```
\setuplabeltext[corollary={Corollary }, theorem={Theorem }, ]
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
\definereferenceformat[cref][label=*]
\setuplabeltext[corollary={Corollary }]


\defineenumeration
  [remark]
  [
    text=Remark,
    location=serried,
    width=fit,
    right={.~},
    prefix=yes,
    % or prefixsegments=chapter:section
    prefixsegments=section,
  ]

\setupnumber[remark][way=bysection]

\defineenumeration
  [theorem]
  [
    text=Theorem,
    location=serried,
    width=fit,
    counter=remark, % only use counter of remark
    style=italic,
    right={.~},
    prefix=yes,
    prefixsegments=section,
  ]

\defineenumeration
  [corollary]
  [
    text=Corollary,
    location=serried,
    width=fit,
    counter=remark, % only use counter of remark
    style=italic,
    right={.~},
    prefix=yes,
    prefixsegments=section,
  ]

\starttext

\startsection
    [title={First section},
     reference={sec:one}]

In \cref[sec:one], we discuss \unknown

\stopsection

\startremark
This is a silly remark.
\stopremark

\starttheorem
This is a deep theorem.
\stoptheorem

\startcorollary[easyresult]
This is an easy corollary.
\stopcorollary

I want \cref[easyresult] to work like \in{Corollary}[easyresult].

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! I assume there is no support for more advanced constructions like `\cref[label1,label2]`, printing "Corollaries 3 and 4" (if `label1` and `label2` correspond to Corollaries 3 and 4).

Comment: @Gaussler: I am not aware of such support. All the information is already there in the `.tuc` file, so it is definitely possible to implement something. Why don't you ask on the context mailing list?