# Show appendix as "Appendix A" instead of "Chapter A" in references

Tags: cross-referencing, context, appendices, cleveref

Here's a ConTeXt document that uses Aditya's solution to ["Cleveref-like command in ConTeXt"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251678/cleveref-like-command-in-context):

```tex
\definereferenceformat[cref][label=*]
\setuplabeltext[chapter=Chapter~,appendix=Appendix~]

\starttext

\startbodymatter
    \startchapter[title={Body chapter},reference={sec:first}]
    \stopchapter
\stopbodymatter

\startappendices
    \startchapter[title={Appendix chapter},reference={sec:second}]
        You are at \cref[sec:second]. Go back to \cref[sec:first]?
    \stopchapter
\stopappendices

\stoptext
```

I expected the output to say:

> You are at Appendix A. Go back to Chapter 1?

Instead, it said:

> You are at Chapter A. Go back to Chapter 1?

Is there a way to have it say "Appendix A" while still using only one command `\cref` for all my references?

#### Environment

```sh
$ context --version
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.04
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2023.03.10 12:15
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkxl/context.mkxl
mtx-context     | current version: 2023.03.10 12:15
```

The build command was just `context example.tex`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please upgrade your code fragments into something we'd like to see here? Here's a quick path for you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . Thank you

Comment: Hi MS-SPO, I'm not sure what needs changing here. Your checklist seems to assume that the reader is using LaTeX.

Comment: @MS-SPO This is already a valid MWE for ConTeXt (and a really good one on top of that). See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10161.

Comment: @MaxChernoff, thank you for your hint. Never worked with Context, as you noticed.

Comment: @Ram, true. See my remark to Max.Sorry for troubling.

Comment: Will be fixed in next upload. But when trying your example I did not get "Appendix" but only "Chapter". I had to do `\definehead[appendix][chapter]` and use that in the appendix to get "Appendix".